# Что написано в коде блока-шаблона?

Tags: javascript, pug, бэм

Пытаюсь понять, как правильно создавать готовую сборку для работы над вэб-проектами и дальнейшей сборки через webpack.

Нашел вроде бы неплохую статью про это: https://nicothin.pro/page/my-start-kit Но некоторые моменты непонятны, а именно:

В статье есть ссылка на "веб-представление" https://nicothin.pro/NTH-start-project/blocks-demo.html в котором есть описания блоков со ссылками на гитхаб.

Например, код блока `footer`:
https://github.com/nicothin/NTH-start-project/blob/master/src/blocks/page-footer/page-footer.pug

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Понятно, что создается миксин `mixin page-footer`, но непонятно, что за `(mods)`? Хоть там и написано, что `mods {string} - принимает список модификаторов`, но ...зачем, для чего и куда это применять? Это же вроде просто миксин, вызвал с помощью `+page-footer` и все, но для чего этот `(mods)`?

Также непонятно, что в целом написано после комментария `// список модификаторов`. Единственное, что я понял, так это что в переменной `var modsList = mods.split(',')` задается разделение модификаторов через запятые и что `modsList[i].trim()` удаляет пробелы у элемента цикла.

Answer (score 0):

В HTML коде [модификаторы](https://ru.bem.info/methodology/quick-start/#%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B8%D1%84%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80) будут выглядеть, как дополнительные классы стилей к блоку с подвалом. Например:

```html
<footer class="page-footer page-footer--black page-footer--big">...</footer>
```

Миксин на скриншоте помогает компоновать этот HTML. Вызываем `page-footer('black,big')` и получаем указанный выше код для подвала.

Фрагмент под комментарием "список модификаторов" обрабатывает параметр `mods`, который мы передали миксину. В этом параметре мы перечислили через запятую окончания классов-модификаторов: `'black,big'`.

1. проверяем, что он задан и что он не пустой:
   `if(typeof(mods) !== 'undefined' && mods)`;
2. разбиваем строку из `mods` на элементы массива;
3. поочерёдно дополняем их до полных названий классов-модификаторов и добавляем к переменной `allMods`:
   `allMods = allMods + ' page-footer--' + modList[i].trim()`

В итоге переменная `allMods` будет содержать строку вида  `page-footer--black page-footer--big`, которую используем в следующем фрагменте кода. Её значение попадёт в атрибут `class` нашего подвала как добавление к основному классу `page-footer`.